# Does Python basically execute code from the top to the bottom?

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, inheritance, interpreted-language

I tried to inherit **"Person" class** to **"Student" class**:

```py
class Student(Person):
  pass

class Person:
  pass
```

But I got this error:

> NameError: name 'Person' is not defined

So, I changed the order of **"Student" and "Person" classes**:

```py
class Person:
  pass

class Student(Person):
  pass
```

Finally, the error was solved.

Does **Python** basically execute code from the top to the bottom?

If yes, are there any special cases which **Python** executes code from the bottom to the top or which **Python** doesn't care about the order of code?

Comment: Yes, Python executes top to bottom.  There are no special cases where it does otherwise, as far as I know.

Comment: There are languages which distinguish between compile-time and runtime code, where it's possible to, for example, call functions before they've been declared, because function declarations are processed at compile-time, but calls at runtime. However, even in those languages, you usually need to define logical relationships in a logical order. I.e. even if class declarations were processed at compile-time, the compiler will still need to know about parent classes before you can try to inherit them.

Comment: If you do `print(1)` followed by `print(2 + 3)`, actually the `2 + 3` gets computed first.

Comment: @KellyBundy Wat?

Comment: @deceze It gets computed during compilation and stored as the constant `5`, which is later loaded and used. See the [disassembly](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM7YoKPr/PzO3IL@oRCEls5iLC0joAbGGuro6V0FRZl6JhqEmlGGkoK1grMkFlNH8/x8A).

Comment: @Kelly That's a compiler optimisation, not sure I'd put this in the same category. It doesn't change anything about the program behaviour like OP's example would.

Comment: @deceze It's half joke, half the-only-thing-I-can-think-of-even-remotely-like-what-they're-asking-for. They did ask for "*any* special cases".